# Convert mm/dd/yyyy format to mm-dd-yyyy for all cell values present in different columns with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, database, datetime-format

I have a requirement to update all the cell values to mm-dd-yyyy format in entire table wherever I find mm/dd/yyyy in multiple columns. Below query works great but what I am looking for is not to write 15 update queries and just write one query to update all the cells regardless of the column name wherever the format is mm/dd/yyyy. How do I achieve this?

Please note, "Tag5" is the column name. I have total 63 columns in the table

```
UPDATE QRDA1_Auto_Template_Details 
SET 
    Tag5 = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Tag5, '%m/%d/%Y'),
            '%Y-%m-%d')
WHERE
    LENGTH(Tag5) = 8
        AND DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Tag5, '%m/%d/%Y'),
            '%Y-%m-%d') IS NOT NULL
        AND Tag5 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: that looks stll lie a bad design, but you have to use infromation_table to get all names and use that in a EXECUTE Query while looping through the re4sult of the columnnames

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off storing dates as dates instead of strings and converting them to the appropriate format for display?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson No because the column is not purely dates. For few rows its date but for few its string value.. We are translating data from excel to db table as it is using jobs.

Comment: @nbk how do I achieve the execute and loop part? Could you share sample or example?

Comment: check for stored procedure and loop  Information:schema Columns , then prepared statement EXECUTE is the rest of it